# Blank upload.php page

Tags: images, uploads, media, library

I am wanting to optimize the images that I have previously installed on my Wordpress site.

I haven't uploaded any images for a while but now when I try to access the Media Library (Media > Library) but now I am been returned a blank page.

Why is this?

I desperately need to access this page to speed up my website. I can still add images through the Media > Add New menu option.

I haven't installed any plugins since the last time I uploaded an image through the Media Library so I can't see it been a conflict from a plugin.

When I view the source code for the page, this is also blank.

Could it be something in the .htaccess file or the header.php? I'm pretty new to using Wordpress to this scale and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd expect a PHP error. Is there anything in your web server error log? Try /var/log/httpd/error.log or /var/log/apache2/error.log. If it's not there, tell us what OS and web server you're using.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say it's externally hosted with my webhost. I have checked their error logs and can't see anything in there.